# SharePoint Sandbox Trouble

Tags: email, sandbox-solution

I have tried creating a mailbox on a site, and I have tried to set-up alerts hoping that the emails each of the accounts are associated with would be used rather than the account emails I created because for some reason, I can't seem to create any mailboxes. I know each account has a "email" of sorts for the username, but I don't know where it goes to, it seems to just disappear. Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong, and me find the internal mailbox.